# realloc() : invalid next size for char* variable

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

This is a function that returns the binary format of decimal as a char *.

```
char* getbinnumbydec(unsigned int a)
{
    char * s;
    unsigned int ost = 0;//remainder of the division variable
    bool loop = true;

    s = (char *)malloc(1);
    while(loop)
    {
        if(a<=1)
            loop = false;

        ost = a%2;//remainder of the division
        a = a/2;

        s = (char*)realloc(s, 2);
        if(ost == 0)
        {
            strcat(s, "0 ");
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(s, "1 ");
        }

    }
    reverse(s, 0, strlen(s)-1);
    strcat(s, "\0");
    return s;
    //returns for example 1 0 1 0 (with space separator)
    //if 10 (decimal) was transfered to this function
```

And it works. But if I pass a number greater than 8191 to this function, then an error message is displayed:

```
*** Error in `./bin': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000f67010 ***
Aborted
```

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Can you give us enough code to compile and run to replicate the error?

Comment: somewhat <O/T>, you're making this needlessly complicated and inefficient with all the `realloc`s.  You'd have to check your architecture, but chances are `unsigned int` is 4 bytes, 32 bits. You want a space every 4 bits, so that's 7 max spaces, plus one for NUL terminator is 40 bytes total. Memory is cheap, just allocate the most you could need and be done with it. 100, for instance, would be more than enough for portability.

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

The `strcat` function requires a string as its first parameter. But the first time you call `strcat`, `s` may or may not contain a string. You need a `*s = 0;` after the first `malloc` for `s`.

Second problem:

Your first time through the loop, you reallocate to two bytes. Then you try to copy "0 " in. But it would take three bytes to hold that string ('0', ' ' and the terminating zero byte). So you haven't allocated enough space.

Third problem:

```
strcat(s, "\0");
```

The `strcat` function requires a string as its first parameter. A string, by definition, terminates with a zero byte. So this serves no purpose. To know where to put the zero byte, it would have to search for the existing zero byte, so one would have to already be there or this would be illegal.